# VideoView does not cover full screen in portrait mode

Tags: android, android-layout, android-videoview

I am making a video player. I have layout like the below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:background="@color/black">
<include layout="@layout/toolbar"/>
<VideoView android:id="@+id/VideoView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
 />
```

When the video view start playing, if it's on portrait screen it leaves space on bottom. I have to do with LinearLayout.

I have tried with Relative Layout as well, which stretched the video.

Let me know how to make the video so that it will cover the aspect ratio issue.

Answer (score 0):

What would be the expected result?

Based on your description I assume the video occupies the full width of the screen. Most popular video formats are 4:3 or 16:9, so the width is larger then the height.

Therefore, in order to preserve the ratio, naturally the height will not be fully filled. In order to have a completely filled height, your video would have to be truncated on the sides in order to preserve the ratio.